# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 while using a static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, arm64

I created a static library (XXX.a) (which has 3 static libraries inside(aaa.a, bbb.a, ccc.a)) and added it into a pre-developed project (someonesProject). When I lipo -info to XXX.a I see the following architectures: armv7, i386, x86_64, arm64

When I try to run this project, I receive an error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_aaa", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in XXX.a(XXX.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see       invocation)

When I remove arm64 from the valid-architectures (arm64, armv7 armv7s) of the project (someonesProject), then I can run the app.

How can I fix this issue, I want to make this project work without removing arm64?

I really need help.

Thanks

E.

Comment: It looks like the linker is getting confused by the arm64 slice of your archive file and failing.  Are you using a very old version of OS X or Xcode?  Are you sure you're using the linker that came with your SDK?

Comment: OS X and Xcode are the latest.

Comment: @Ervin Aydin Did you manage to solve the issue? or to find the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your static libraries have to be compatible with arm64 if you want to compile your project with this architecture.
So I guess at least one of aaa.a, bbb.a and ccc.a is not compatible with arm64.

Comment: Thanks KIDdAe for your answer. When I lipo -info, I can see that aaa.a and bbb.a do not support arm64. but the early version of the same static library (XXX.a) containing the same (aaa.a, bbb.a, ccc.a) static libraries inside are being used in an app which has valid-architecture=arm64 ?